# How to pass message into rosservice using args

Tags: ros-melodic, rosservice, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please refer to the package
[ethzasl_icp_mapper](https://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_icp_mapper)'s node **matcher_service**

Matcher Service node offers a Service  *match_clouds*, which is by description:

> <...> takes two
> sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 messages as
> inputs (the first is the reference and
> the second the reading) and provides a
> geometry_msgs/Transform message as
> output.

Thus, the service structure is the following:

```
sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 reference
sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 readings
---
geometry_msgs/Transform transform
```

And required arguments are `reference` and `readings`

I have two topics with the same msgs type, but cannot understand how to provide them properly?

Double_tabbing gives a skeleton, but I'd be happy to make them taken from topics aready existing, than typing myself.

```
Service arguments are: [reference.header.seq reference.header.stamp reference.header.frame_id reference.height reference.width reference.fields reference.is_bigendian reference.point_step reference.row_step reference.data reference.is_dense readings.header.seq readings.header.stamp readings.header.frame_id readings.height readings.width readings.fields readings.is_bigendian readings.point_step readings.row_step readings.data readings.is_dense]
```

**[EDIT]**

Thanks @fexner for your answer, your logic is completely right, I think it can be accepted.

After digging up, I realized, that's what [ROS Client](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingServiceClient.Writing_the_Client_Node) stands for. I completely forget about it.

That means, parsing arguments from the command line is only a little part of ServiceClient tool.
Unfortunately, tutorials only consist of sums of 1+3, without more advanced implementations.

**[EDIT 2]**

Got lucky to find **[lots of practical examples](https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/ros/ServiceClient/call/cpp-serviceclient-call-method-examples.html)**, hopefully gets helpful for those, who tries to implement something more than prime numbers addition:)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339928/how-to-pass-message-into-rosservice-using-args/) by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2019-12-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) on 2019-12-14**:
For reference [matcher_service node](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_icp_mapping/blob/reintegrate/master_into_indigo_devel/ethzasl_icp_mapper/src/matcher_service.cpp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Filling `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` fields from the command lines is probably not recommended, as they usually contain quite a lot of data.

To fill this service's request using data from topics, you probably would have to write a short wrapper node that subscribes to those topics, saves data in two cache variables and offers a service which will call the `matcher_service` using the two cache variables.

---

Originally posted by [fexner](https://answers.ros.org/users/26760/fexner/) with karma: 221 on 2019-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) on 2019-12-16**:
Question updated for more details